# How to Compare new entry with the already existed one in Core data?

Tags: ios, core-data

I want to save some data that consist of link,title,description,time into core data and the data should be unique, I want to set primary key for title.

Comment: how to compare the new one with the already existed one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set a Primary key in Core Data as it not a database it is an object-graph persistence framework. core data is a persistance framework more than a general purpose database, it abstracts the primary key.
use `objectID` property of `NSManagedObject` This would give you a unique reference to your object.

Comment: Then is there any possible way to compare the new entry with the already existed one?